# Export Mageanto Data (Categories and Products)

Tags: php, mysql, magento, import, export

I want to transfer same Magento data to my own website, such as existing Categories (name and cid) and Products (name, description, id, cid, image).

is there an easy way to do that?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, please do research on import/export functionality on magento. It allows you to export file in `csv` format. Navigate to `backend>system>import/export`.